# How to read a csv dataset when converting to a float that contain nan's

Tags: python, list

I have a dataset containing XY coordinates.

```
df:
,Time_x,P1_X,P1_Y,P2_X,P2_Y,P3_X,P3_Y,P4_X,P4_Y,P5_X,P5_Y,P6_X,P6_Y,P7_X,P7_Y,P8_X,P8_Y,P9_X,P9_Y,P10_X,P10_Y,P11_X,P11_Y,P12_X,P12_Y,13_X,P13_Y,MP14_X,P14_Y,P15_X,P15_Y,P16_X,P16_Y,P17_X,P17_Y,P18_X,P18_Y,P19_X,P19_Y,P20_X,P20_Y,P21_X,P21_Y
0,10:39.2,65.74835477,45.10031842,,,73.73594438,-3.516560206,61.90991549,41.79799446,67.06663915,-24.6161481,77.13941436,-22.98303729,,,93.94853726,3.51273869,56.51826591,28.44337707,70.2095591,11.06472095,73.07962202,-35.54419066,,,69.78626105,45.73116662,73.34402753,29.26475119,64.72901307,-40.68655635,70.90387539,6.110571001,,,70.94140139,-45.11483157,42.78164288,3.001018117,61.77394225,-1.052283362,72.07455255,38.61536724
1,10:39.3,65.7684248,45.15534694,,,73.69043192,-3.346474054,61.69908417,41.78674915,67.18671591,-24.58808435,77.17029694,-23.02517617,,,93.89646426,3.528745627,56.5427544,28.38370261,70.19822793,10.99883442,73.1451771,-35.47750429,,,69.793868,45.85988623,73.19566664,29.30369084,64.95606388,-40.77004615,70.91007366,6.101747301,,,71.04051167,-45.29294224,42.83526579,3.015121968,61.82365038,-0.992786137,72.11546062,38.71278829
2,10:39.4,65.7834979,45.23761992,,,73.63024857,-3.170554247,61.69908417,41.78674915,67.31838918,-24.56060698,77.19810461,-23.05487575,,,93.83429634,3.549376049,56.58563081,28.31338862,70.20044679,10.91910555,73.19935612,-35.41010968,,,69.793868,45.85988623,73.03211884,29.35832821,65.18572736,-40.83631919,70.90862232,6.095069866,,,71.14518241,-45.50045784,42.91278516,3.042026157,61.89316922,-0.908282198,72.15835354,38.79647675
3,10:39.5,65.77840928,45.33358677,,,73.56738903,-3.004921009,61.49273767,41.78345615,67.45296434,-24.49742142,77.24683185,-23.0746477,,,93.75341377,3.57316934,56.58563081,28.31338862,70.21321398,10.82616678,73.24568774,-35.32805879,,,69.76596819,46.01111858,72.86184401,29.42608261,65.44690548,-40.85525672,70.89755931,6.089554125,,,71.14518241,-45.50045784,43.00642078,3.080217618,61.97555301,-0.809576222,72.19068707,38.85755563
4,10:39.6,65.77840928,45.33358677,,,73.50806135,-2.855633447,61.3237999,41.7645154,67.45296434,-24.49742142,77.31339655,-23.08972129,,,93.64174988,3.597532195,56.65025238,28.22321974,70.23114884,10.71566289,73.2926943,-35.21882915,,,69.71782002,46.17421599,72.68560842,29.51043513,65.74782799,-40.84255022,70.87891012,6.077805367,,,71.23816153,-45.7142832,43.10742527,3.116367715,62.05509887,-0.701754721,72.21717228,38.89813378
5,10:39.7,65.75014637,45.43899962,,,73.50806135,-2.855633447,61.19700699,41.7258644,67.58915846,-24.37106504,77.38130274,-23.10307092,,,93.51787893,3.634328031,56.72537119,28.09054972,70.24967103,10.59080123,73.2926943,-35.21882915,,,69.67960579,46.33094215,72.49404407,29.59751202,66.06115669,-40.83993114,70.86080027,6.05285653,,,71.31336268,-45.90846101,43.2195678,3.144570182,62.12609805,-0.586598609,72.25515393,38.91940055
6,10:39.8,65.72415694,45.5638032,,,73.44657692,-2.72192294,61.080345,41.70838991,67.71533117,-24.18657972,77.44308531,-23.11845241,,,93.38796245,3.688287535,56.79638669,27.90929345,70.27002355,10.45441014,73.34211471,-35.08260266,,,69.65662456,46.47998758,72.27043085,29.67176654,66.35939869,-40.86560837,70.8555952,6.011435456,,,71.3879848,-46.08573746,43.35090951,3.165650171,62.19517251,-0.469470394,72.29242686,38.92721258
7,10:39.9,65.72415694,45.5638032,,,73.34321435,-2.484931546,60.96876103,41.71902907,67.91714413,-23.76286234,77.50996588,-23.13078797,,,93.2338117,3.747387513,56.79638669,27.90929345,70.30195937,10.30869873,73.40204147,-34.76055633,,,69.63899826,46.62648261,72.01016239,29.73848462,66.61697312,-40.93431941,70.84946964,5.956736242,,,71.3879848,-46.08573746,43.50531444,3.182638905,62.26571559,-0.349540463,72.306823,38.92576468
8,10:40.0,65.72640511,45.90044609,,,73.34321435,-2.484931546,60.85749825,41.72228418,67.91714413,-23.76286234,77.50996588,-23.13078797,,,93.04594414,3.804332611,56.90708858,27.47107403,70.30195937,10.30869873,73.40204147,-34.76055633,,,69.62833124,46.75870303,72.01016239,29.73848462,66.81844484,-41.05910571,70.83004887,5.88048307,,,71.53464719,-46.44939722,43.67970504,3.199540663,62.26571559,-0.349540463,72.28640137,38.91523022
9,10:40.1,65.73471059,46.09055191,,,73.29319933,-2.386860276,60.73665589,41.69825068,68.00127816,-23.52089544,77.59634783,-23.11668408,,,92.83052909,3.855217565,56.99476178,27.23257625,70.35348817,10.16930434,73.42987865,-34.57575831,,,69.63765824,46.87567533,71.72443403,29.79967959,66.98755098,-41.21757769,70.80317812,5.787732612,,,71.59706935,-46.62810448,43.86089318,3.230902964,62.34316807,-0.222178787,72.22350189,38.89193796
10,10:40.2,65.75977889,46.26942327,,,73.21734165,-2.316126343,60.59930975,41.65445171,68.0724164,-23.24021663,77.70931884,-23.05410585,,,92.83052909,3.855217565,57.13943331,26.97645306,70.43207023,10.04514328,73.4723494,-34.37979511,,,69.67617065,46.96242203,71.41605592,29.85130535,67.15540192,-41.38391162,70.77290365,5.700544001,,,71.64158584,-46.79708835,44.03704526,3.277926599,62.43312018,-0.075105951,72.1268057,38.86084053
11,10:40.3,65.81233364,46.43336273,,,73.11593567,-2.283506162,60.4293884,41.60374479,68.12004174,-22.92661317,77.83238644,-22.93583526,,,92.58178284,3.893350665,57.32406047,26.71522467,70.54228257,9.919741549,73.50151508,-34.15533975,,,69.74884487,46.99223148,71.07998047,29.8888544,67.15540192,-41.38391162,70.73944069,5.618859806,,,71.67457763,-46.96450445,44.20608898,3.33131815,62.53533464,0.085780268,72.02574333,38.8381385
12,10:40.4,65.86936174,46.57694451,,,72.9778864,-2.291612521,60.2405844,41.54929492,68.14726428,-22.57302135,77.93896505,-22.75736162,,,92.29630715,3.930296742,57.51951925,26.45390304,70.67200238,9.775836947,73.50070864,-33.91179722,,,69.85140998,47.00004988,70.71741586,29.91020527,67.31475844,-41.57316916,70.69673039,5.516469874,,,71.73266998,-47.15102674,44.36917309,3.39687465,62.65511724,0.239597606,72.02574333,38.8381385
13,10:40.5,65.91158366,46.6940655,,,72.80148309,-2.319605446,60.06779082,41.49258775,68.17052906,-22.18436155,78.01358917,-22.52816761,,,91.99251252,3.977587778,57.70644985,26.17801664,70.81201138,9.603164634,73.49263778,-33.68107782,,,69.96927481,47.03273893,70.33260823,29.92346405,67.44615069,-41.77504126,70.63678435,5.375363071,,,71.81438808,-47.34998667,44.36917309,3.39687465,62.80495163,0.397775745,71.95500412,38.81482723
```

I read the file and append all the x-coordinates and all the y-coordinates such:

```
visuals = [[],[]]

with open('widexy.csv') as csvfile :
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1
            continue
        visuals[0].append([float(row[3]),float(row[5]),float(row[7])])
        visuals[1].append([float(row[2]),float(row[4]),float(row[6])])
```

This works when there is a complete dataset that does not contain any nan's. However I get a

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

when values are missing.

My question is: how do I read the csv file when data is missing?

Would is be easier to read the complete dataset and write an `if statement` that removes undesired values. Or is there a simpler way to read the dataset without undesired values?

I tried to run:

```
try:
    visuals[0].append([float(row[3]),float(row[5]),float(row[7])])
    visuals[1].append([float(row[2]),float(row[4]),float(row[6])])
except ValueError:
    continue
```

But this only worked when there was data in every row. It wouldn't work when data was missing in any row(which is 90% of the time).

```
with open('widexy.csv') as csvfile :
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1
            continue
        def from_float(value):
            try:
                return float(value)
            except ValueError:
                return float('nan')
            visuals[0].append([from_float(row[3]),from_float(row[5]),from_float(row[7])])
            visuals[1].append([from_float(row[2]),from_float(row[4]),from_float(row[6])])
```

Comment: check all rows for int..

Comment: What are the actual contents of your csv file? What's in your question is not what's actually in it. Please open the file in a text editor and copy what's displayed and paste that into your question (indented by 4 spaces like code).

Comment: Try substituting default value as 0.00 like   visuals[1].append([float(row[2] if row[2] else 0.0),float(row[4] if row[4] else 0.0 ),float(row[6] if row[6] else 0.0)])

Comment: I'm using the data to make a scatter plot so If I did that I'd have points at 0,0 which I don't want.

Comment: Sample of the dataset has been adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
visuals[0].append([float(row[3]),float(row[5]),float(row[7])])
```

Try something like:

```
def from_float(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return float('nan')
```

Then:

```
visuals[0].append([from_float(row[3]), from_float(row[5]), from_float(row[7])])
```

Comment: That returns an empty list. I didn't want to add a lot of data but there are x,y coordinates missing throughout each row. I'll attach in the code a failed attempt

Comment: So your edit does not show you tried what I suggested.  My code will not give an empty list.

Comment: I'll attach your code in the question to see if it is written as intended.

Comment: The last bit of code in the question returns an empty list. Is it written correctly?

Comment: No, it is not.  You need the function `from_float()`, not `float()`

Comment: Sorry. I've adjusted the code and have the same issue. When I perform a `print` function on `visuals[0]` or `visuals[1]`, it returns `[]`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to convert empty string('') to float. That is not possible. 
Replace '' with Nan.Then Try to convert.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
widexy= pd.read_csv("widexy.csv")
widexy['AC_X'].replace('',np.Nan)
#like this replace '' with Nan for every row 
#Then convert complete dataFrame into float like below
widexy.astype(float)
#Then add each row like this and create new row
df['FinalX'] = df['AB_X'] + df['AC_X'] + df['AD_X']
#like this do for y
```

Comment: I've tried both ways. As nan's and as `''`. Neither works.

Comment: did you replace ' ' to Nan ? like this widexy['AC_X'].replace('',np.Nan)

Comment: use like this convert whole dataframe to string once u replace the empty string with nan.  widexy.astype(float)